# How can I use TypeGuards to narrow types for multiple object fields in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing, type-narrowing

Say I've got a `Foo` object which has multiple fields which can either be `None` or some other type. Whether or not the field is `None` relates to whether other fields are `None` or not, so by checking one field, I can instantly know if the other fields are `None`.

I understand this is terrible class design, but I'm not able to modify it as it is other people's code that I am annotating.

It looks like `TypeGuard`s introduced in [PEP 647](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/) are my best bet for adding this functionality, but I can't figure out how I could specifically apply them to this situation. I've attached an attempt I made with subclasses, but it fails both in MyPy and in Pyright.

```py
from typing import Optional
from typing_extensions import TypeGuard

class Foo:
    """A class containing the parameters `value`, `values` and `other`. If 
    `values` is `None` then both the others are not, and if the others are not
    then `values` is.
    """
    def __init__(self, value: 'int | list[int]', other: Optional[int]) -> None:
        is_singular = isinstance(value, int)
        self.value = value if is_singular else None
        self.values = None if is_singular else value
        if is_singular:
            assert other is not None
        else:
            assert other is None
        self.other = other

class SingularFoo(Foo):
    """A subclass for an instance of `Foo` where `values` is `None`
    """
    def __init__(self, value: int, other: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(value, other)

class MultiFoo(Foo):
    """A subclass for an instance of `Foo` where `values` is not `None`
    """
    def __init__(self, value: list[int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(value, None)

def isFooSingular(f: Foo) -> TypeGuard[SingularFoo]:
    """A type guard that returns whether `f` is singular (meaning that `values`
    is `None` and `value` and `other` are not)
    """
    return f.value is not None

# Create a singular `Foo`
my_foo = Foo(1, 2)
# Type guard
assert isFooSingular(my_foo)
# After the type guard, both should be considered as `int`
#
# Errors from MyPy:
# * Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "None")
# * Unsupported operand types for + ("List[int]" and "int")
# * Unsupported operand types for + ("List[int]" and "None")
# * Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
# * Unsupported left operand type for + ("None")
print(my_foo.value + my_foo.other)
```

How can I modify this code such that the type guard performs the desired type narrowing operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you're explicit about the types in `SingularFoo`? This seems to make `mypy` happy:

```
class SingularFoo(Foo):
    """A subclass for an instance of `Foo` where `values` is `None`"""

    value: int
    other: int

    def __init__(self, value: int, other: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(value, other)
```