# Type Narrowing of Class Attributes in Python (TypeGuard) without Subclassing

Tags: python, python-typing, typeguards, type-narrowing

Consider I have a python class that has a attributes (i.e. a dataclass, pydantic, attrs, django model, ...) that consist of a union, i.e. None and and a state.
Now I have a complex checking function that checks some values.

If I use this checking function, I want to tell the type checker, that some of my class attributes are narrowed.

For instance see this simplified example:

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import TypeGuard


@dataclasses.dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    state: tuple[int, int] | None
    name: str
    # Assume many more data attributes


class SomeDataClassWithSetState(SomeDataClass):
    state: tuple[int, int]


def complex_check(data: SomeDataClass) -> TypeGuard[SomeDataClassWithSetState]:
    # Assume some complex checks here, for simplicity it is only:
    return data.state is not None and data.name.startswith("SPECIAL")


def get_sum(data: SomeDataClass) -> int:
    if complex_check(data):
        return data.state[0] + data.state[1]
    return 0
```

[Explore on mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=78110cda92c7e3127e0ab562c54017d1)

As seen it is possible to do this with subclasses, which for various reason is **not** an option for me:

- it introduces a lot of duplication
- some possible libraries used for dataclasses are not happy with being subclasses without side condition
- there could be some Metaclass or `__subclasses__` magic that handles all subclass specially, i.e.  creating database for the dataclasses

So is there an option to type narrow a(n) attribute(s) of a class without introducing a solely new class, [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194509)?

Comment: You seem intent on using `typing.TypeGuard`, which relies on two _distinct types_ to be useful. It is not entirely clear, what your _actual_ goal is, but my guess is that `TypeGuard` is not the way to get there. Based on your example, is your goal to have a type-safe way to assume the `SomeDataClass.state` attribute is a `tuple` (and not `None`) in the `get_sum` function?

Comment: The idea here is that the `complex_check` function is intended to be used everyhwhere in the code and I don't want `assert data.state is not None` calls in all the if branches, because this has already been verified by `complex_check`. I only need the type checker to understand this.
Also it is just a simple example, the `complex_check` function could check a number of arguments, that could be potentially type narrowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You cannot narrow the type of an attribute. You can only narrow the type of an object.

As I already mentioned in my comment, for [`typing.TypeGuard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard) to be useful it relies on **two distinct types** `T` and `S`. Then, depending on the returned `bool`, the type guard function tells the type checker to assume the object to be either `T` or `S`.

You say, you don't want to have another class/subclass alongside `SomeDataClass` for various (vaguely valid) reasons. But if you don't have another type, then `TypeGuard` is useless. So that is not the route to take here.

I understand that you want to reduce the type-safety checks like `if obj.state is None` because you may need to access the `state` attribute in multiple different places in your code. You must have some place in your code, where you create/mutate a `SomeDataClass` instance in a way that *ensures* its `state` attribute is not `None`. One solution then is to have a getter for that attribute that performs the type-safety check and only ever returns the narrower type or raises an error. I typically do this via `@property` for improved readability. Example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    name: str
    optional_state: tuple[int, int] | None = None

    @property
    def state(self) -> tuple[int, int]:
        if self.optional_state is None:
            raise RuntimeError("or some other appropriate exception")
        return self.optional_state


def set_state(obj: SomeDataClass, value: tuple[int, int]) -> None:
    obj.optional_state = value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = SomeDataClass(optional_state=(1, 2), name="foo")
    bar = SomeDataClass(name="bar")
    baz = SomeDataClass(name="baz")
    set_state(bar, (2, 3))
    print(foo.state)
    print(bar.state)
    try:
        print(baz.state)
    except RuntimeError:
        print("baz has no state")
```

I realize you mean there are many more checks happening in `complex_check`, but either that function *doesn't* change the type of `data` or it *does*. If the type remains the same, you need to introduce type-safety for attributes like `state` in some other place, which is why I suggest a getter method.

Another option is obviously to have a separate class, which is what is typically done with `FastAPI`/`Pydantic`/`SQLModel` for example and use [clever inheritance](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/multiple-models/#the-heroread-data-model) to reduce code duplication. You mentioned this *may* cause problems because of subclassing magic. Well, if it does, use the other approach, but I can't think of an example that would cause the problems you mentioned. Maybe you can be more specific and show a case where subclassing would lead to problems.

Comment: The property Idea is great.

Comment: Just found this issues again, facing the same problem in codebase with **a lot** of dataclasses with optional properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Protocol` class and `TypeVar`'s to support a wider range of potential `state` options.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
from typing import TypeGuard, TYPE_CHECKING, Literal

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

    _T = TypeVar("_T")

    class _StateProtocol(Protocol[_T]):
        state: _T


@dataclasses.dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    state: tuple[int, int] | Literal["FOO"] | None
    name: str


def is_tuple_state(data: SomeDataClass) -> TypeGuard[_StateProtocol[tuple[int, int]]]:
    # Assume some complex checks here, for simplicity it is only:
    return isinstance(data.state, tuple) and data.name.startswith("SPECIAL")


def is_foo_state(data: SomeDataClass) -> TypeGuard[_StateProtocol[Literal["FOO"]]]:
    # Assume some complex checks here, for simplicity it is only:
    return data.state == "FOO"


def get_sum(data: SomeDataClass) -> int:
    if is_tuple_state(data):
        return data.state[0] + data.state[1]
    if is_foo_state(data):
        return -1

    return 0


def main():
    assert get_sum(SomeDataClass(None, "SPECIAL")) == 0
    assert get_sum(SomeDataClass((1, 2), "SPECIAL")) == 3
    assert get_sum(SomeDataClass("FOO", "SPECIAL")) == -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```