# Mypy is not happy with type after helper function ensures the type

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a function X where instance variable V of class A could be either None or class B instance. Inside function X I am using a helper function Y, which is raising an exception if V is None. I would assume that mypy would recognize this as assurance that V is then class B instance. In function X I continue to treat V as a class B instance, however mypy keeps complaining that V could still be None. Am I missing something, or is just mypy not smart enough to recognize this?

I have this:

```
    def get_list_from_darwin (self, url: str, view: Dict[str, str], original_time) -> List[str]:
        self._handler_checker([self.mongo_handler, self.darwin_handler])
        change_list = self.darwin_handler.send_request_to_darwin(url, view)
        ...

    def _handler_checker(self, handlers_to_check: List[Union[MongoHandler, DarwinHandler, ArangoHandler]]) -> None:
        handlers_missing = []
        for handler in handlers_to_check:
            if not handler:
                handlers_missing.append(handler.__class__.__name__)

        if handlers_missing:
            raise HandlerNotDefinedError('Following handlers not defined '
                                         f'for {self.name} flow: {handlers_missing}')
```

Mypy is complaining on this line: `change_list = self.darwin_handler.send_request_to_darwin(url, view)` : *Item "None" of "DarwinHandler | None" has no attribute "send_request_to_darwin" Mypy union-attr* and others which are irrelevant at this point....

self.darwin_handler is typed as following: `darwin_handler: Optional[DarwinHandler ] = None`

I was expecting that after running *_handler_checker* mypy would recongize self.darwin_handler as DarwinHandler instance.

Comment: "I was expecting that after running _handler_checker mypy would recongize self.darwin_handler as DarwinHandler instance." no, it won't

Comment: I can see that, but is is mypy limitation, or am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: In the meantime I edited the _handler_checker func, as it was a bit buggy, however it is not strictly related to this issue:

Comment: mypy isn't expected to be able to infer anything here. here is what you can expect as far as type narrowing in mypy: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html

What you expect is pretty extreme

Comment: ```
    def _handler_checker(
        self,
        handlers_to_check:
            List[Union[Optional[MongoHandler],
                       Optional[DarwinHandler],
                       Optional[ArangoHandler]]
                 ]
            ) -> None:
        for handler in handlers_to_check:
            if not handler:
                self.log_and_publish_error(f'Handler(s) not defined for base_flow in {self.name}')
                raise HandlerNotDefinedError(f'Handler(s) not defined for base_flow in {self.name}')
```

Comment: as an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. version specific tags can go for questions that apply only to specific versions, but as of now, Python 3 is assumed to be what you are talking about (since Python 2 is well-passed it's EOL)

Comment: think about it this way, you basically want the type checker to run your program here. type narrowing pretty much always applies to a variable in a specific scope. not to attributes in a class

Comment: So see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624626/type-narrowing-of-class-attributes-in-python-typeguard-without-subclassing which I think is pretty much an appropriate duplicate target for this question

Comment: thanks man! the answer you referred actually helped... sorry for duplications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Narrowing of Class Attributes in Python (TypeGuard) without Subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624626/type-narrowing-of-class-attributes-in-python-typeguard-without-subclassing)